# react router persist route history on page reload

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

Is there any way I could persist react route history on page reload and pass it to my component.
Ex:- I am on a dashboard component with link "/" then I go to another component using link "/ab" then I go to another component using Link "/bcd".

Flow = "/"->"/ab"->"/bcd"

Now when I reload the page when I am on "/bcd" the router is not persisting the older routes. So as a result I can't return to the previous components/pages. How could I return to previous components even after page reload?

I am using HashRouter. and React-router version is 4.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, @babs' solution will utilize the browser's back capability to simply go back a page, but I had a similar requirement to your issue where I needed to track where a user came from in the app, persisting through page reloads/refreshes. We're using redux and have a history listener on the router that dispatches a "LOCATION_CHANGE" for every navigation.

The problem was it only gives you part of the story and is fired *after* the route changes, so seeing where the route was from was a no-go. I created a history reducer that simply stores in state a queue/stack of the last N changes paired with a set of selectors that expose to the app the current (top) and previous (top - 1) location/history objects. This is because while react-router's [history *is* mutable](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history/history-is-mutable) it doesn't provide all what you expect*.

The basic pattern to listen for changes is:

```
// Listen for changes to the current location.
const unlisten = history.listen((location, action) => {
  // location is an object like window.location
  console.log(action, location.pathname, location.state);
});
```

If you're not using a state management like Redux you can still use this callback to store a history of sorts in your route component, or root app component where you create the router history object. Pass as props to children or use the new context system, or upgrade and use redux, to get your history.

* [MemoryHistory](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/GettingStarted.md#properties) does actually provide a history stack that you can access

Comment: Thanks for answering I tried using similar approach by listening to history on route change and pushing it onto the localstorage but I am confused here if I save the history objects inside stack/queue how do I pass it down to my app on page refresh?

Comment: I think I'd create a utility function that pulls your local storage that you can call in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle function or in a "on mount" `useEffect` hook.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the following function, this has nothing to do with react-router. It's just using the logic from the browsers back button:

```
function goBack() { 
   window.history.back();
}
```